# I can read and write from a txt file internal storage (documents folder) but cannot browse to that location because it doesn't exist

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Alright so I've managed to read/write files programatically in C# in Xamarin Studio. And it's working on my device.

However, when I output the exact path that the file is being written to, to the console, that path doesn't even exist anywhere in the entire phone!!!!

How is that?

```
using System;
using System.IO;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace ToolbarSample
{
    [Activity(Label = "ToolbarSample", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            string content = "Jason rules";
            string filename = "file.txt";

            var documents = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button);
            TextView viewer = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

            if (File.Exists(documents + @"/" + filename))
            {
                string newContent = File.ReadAllText(documents + @"/" + filename);

                if (viewer != null)
                {
                    viewer.Text = newContent;
                    Console.WriteLine("File exists in: " + documents + @"/" + filename);
                }
            }

            if (button != null)
            {
                button.Click += delegate
                {
                        button.Enabled = false;

                        if (!Directory.Exists(documents))
                        {
                            viewer.Text = "Directory not found: " + documents;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Directory exists.");

                            File.WriteAllText(documents + @"/" + filename, content);

                            if (!File.Exists(documents + @"/" + filename))
                            {
                                viewer.Text = "File not found: " + documents + @"/" + filename;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string newContent = File.ReadAllText(documents + @"/" + filename);

                                if (viewer != null)
                                {
                                    viewer.Text = newContent;
                                    Console.WriteLine("File exists in: " + documents + @"/" + filename);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following gets outputted to the console upon successful read from internal sdcard:

> Directory exists. File exists in:
>   /data/data/ToolbarSample.ToolbarSample/files/file.txt

But using (many different) file managers - all with root access - and hidden files being shown - I cannot navigate to that path because it does not exist. I even did a whole phone search for "file.txt" and not a single result showed up. Yet I am able to read that file whenever I open my app and click the button.

Comment: Which part of that path does not exist?

Comment: @Simon the whole thing. Even the first part: data/data. There is not a single location on the whole phone which includes a sub folder named data where its parent folder is also called data. I did manage to find a files folder inside my apps folder but that only contains a dll file and a Microsoft access file (which for some reason wont open in Microsoft access)

Comment: You do not have the correct file explorers then.  /data/ exists on all Android phones.  Try this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer&hl=en.  Not all root explorers are equal.

Comment: Thanks @Simon! I can see it now. Do you know if it's there is a standard., publicly accessibly Documents folder on android that non root users and apps can access?

Comment: No there is not.  Apps are only supposed to share data via `Intents`.  The document centric approach is not part of a mobile operating system.  In fact, apart from some legacy stuff in Windows for backwards compatibility, it is not part of any modern operating system.

Comment: @Simon I'm really hating this. So they expect everyone to use cloud storage then in order to be able to easily access their files anywhere? They don't seem to take into account situations where there is no internet access or its too slow or we just want to save a file to our phone and be able to plug the phone into a computer and transfer it via usb. Also, Windows Phone 8.1 by popular demand now has a full file system that any user can browse and MS also created a File Explorer app for it too.

Comment: You've missed the point entirely.  No "public" documents folder has nothing to do with cloud storage, it just has no use.  What use scenario is there that you want to support?

Comment: By a regular user not being able to save a file to a public folder which can be viewed using Windows file explorer on the desktop they're already forcing many users to use cloud storage so they can 'sync' them instead. However cloud storage is not the best solution for everyone. You could argue that the user child just save the file in some other random folder that is accessible without root access but then that would just feel unnatural and hacky and difficult for some to grasp. I think there needs to be a documents folder that can be accessed by apps and other devices via USB.

Comment: I still don't get what you are trying to do.  You can browse the SDCard in Windows Explorer easily.  Modern OSes are task focused, not document focused.  Maybe I just don't understand what you are trying to do.  Every photo and video I take are available to me on all my devices without having to think about the "location" where I store them.  Why should I care?

Comment: I dunno. I understand your point. I guess I'm still set in my old ways.

Comment: @jay_t55 I don't mean to be rude, but there are many answers that can be easily found online, to questions you have asked here on StackOverflow. Maybe you could try changing the way you search for things, as it could give you better search results if you limit your query to just the most relavent keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file at the location you have specified does exist. You cannot access that location from your PC via USB and File Explorer, but you can access the location (and the file) if you use a good File Manager app like Root Explorer.

If you really want your users to be able to access these saved files, I'd suggest that you save these files to a better location so that the user can easily transfer files from their phone to the computer via USB.

Comment: How do u define a better location? Or, how can a get a directory which is also visible to user explorer?

Answer (score 0):

> It quite simple both Read/Write  data from File .

```
public String ReadFileData()
    {
        var path = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
        var filename = Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "loginSystem.txt");
        String line;
        objData = new List<UsersData>();
        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filename);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] words = line.Split(',');
            if (words.Length != 1)
                objData.Add(new UsersData(words[0], words[1], words[2]));
        }

        file.Close();
        return String.Empty;
    }
```

> Save data into file

```
 private string SaveDataToSd(String FirstName, String Address, String Password)
    {
        var path = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
        var filename = Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "loginSystem.txt");
        String contents = FirstName + "," + Password + "," + Address;
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter data_file = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
            {
                data_file.WriteLine(contents);
            }
            return contents;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.SetMessage(ex.InnerException + "Saving file went wrong");
                builder.SetTitle("Unable to save file");
                builder.Show();
            });
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Pandey Omi can you help me.

Its saying "the type or namespace name 'android' could not be found"

How to import "Android" namespace in visual studio?

Comment: Is that for only SdCard?  or can be used for also internal storage ?